# how to get last inserted record in symfony1.4

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

how to get last inserted record in symfony1.4
i do not have much knowledge of symfony.
and i need the the id of last inserted record in symfony1.4, so If you have any idea please let me know.

```
public function executeAddquestion(sfWebRequest $request)
{
$q=$this->getUser()->getAttribute('quiz');
    $qs=$this->getUser()->getAttribute('questions');
$t = new test();
$t->setTestName($q);
$t->setTestQuestions($qs);
$t->save();
$t->getId();
}
```

the above code, which can i tried. but not got anything.
so please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the id but not storing it anywhere?

Try the following:

```
$lastId = $t->getId();
```

Comment: They say: *getId() will only work if your primary key column is named "id"*. Read here, people faced the same problem: http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/7253/